# Ubuntu Server, services crashing yet server stays up with call trace

Tags: ubuntu, server-crashes

I have a strange issue with our Ubuntu 12.04LTS server.

it has happened twice now and with a gap of around a week.

The server services (apache, ssh, smnp, webmin, just the ones i tested) all stop responding, however ping is fine and VLC continues to stream.

I can get access via iDrac and i have a screen dump of what was on the screen:

[image: stack trace]

To get the server to work again we have to perform a reboot.

I know there is very little information here. Please let me know what more i can provide and i will.

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs for around the times it has happened?

Comment: nothing i'm afraid, is there anything i can run in back ground to catch and report next time?